# Ubuntu 20.04 slow startup

Tags: boot, startup

I just installed ubuntu 20.4 after partitioning my windows system and installing on a partition. But the startup is really slow. Taking up to 15 - 20 minutes. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of information here. Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) the brand/model of your computer (2) the hardware specifications (3) the Terminal output of `systemd-analyze blame`. With this, it may be possible to offer some solutions 

Comment: you can look into log files